# How to get name, price and image of product using EntityFieldQuery()

Tags: database

Right now i am using this which doen't give me the name of the product or the price or location of the product image.

```
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_product');
    $query->fieldOrderBy('commerce_price', 'amount', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();
```

which give this result

```
Array
(
    [commerce_product] => Array
        (
            [56] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 56
                    [revision_id] => 55
                    [type] => product
                )

            [50] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 50
                    [revision_id] => 49
                    [type] => testcamera
                )

            [28] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 28
                    [revision_id] => 28
                    [type] => cameras
                )
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can now load the product using commerce_product_load($product_id); Then you will see price, fields, etc. You could also put all the product_id's in an array, then load them all with commerce_product_load_multiple($product_ids);

Comment: Do i just pass the $result to commerce_product_load($result); or do i use the id from the array?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) @Krish. Your current approach of just trying to hack together a solution won't work with Drupal, it's too complicated. You need to understand how the entity API works to make any sense of Drupal Commerce, there's a steep learning curve ahead if you're just starting out with Drupal (trust me, been there, got the t-shirt)